# Mongoose - How do I find a specific document by matching an element in an array of object Ids in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema like so:

```
var accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    accountName: String,
    accountType: { type: String, default: 'Individual Account' },
    accountNumber: { type: String, unique: true },
    accountActive: Boolean,
    investment: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Investment'
        }
      ]
  })
    
  module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema);
```

And I will like to find the `Account` document that has a specific `object id` in the investment array.

```
"investment": [
        {
            "$oid": "5f353184c2daaf0f5c661ea7"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "5f3531acc2daaf0f5c661ea9"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "5f366e873d566938f81b94a8"
        },
]
```

I have tried the code below but I keep getting an empty array:

```
Account.find().elemMatch('investment', { id: investment.id }).exec(function(err, account){
        console.log(account)
    });
```

What am I doing wrong? I expected elemMatch to work according to the [mongoose document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-elemMatch). On debug I see that the code is correctly translated to mongodb.

```
accounts find {"investment":{"$elemMatch":{"id":"5f3531acc2daaf0f5c661ea9"}}} {"projection":{}}
```

Can anyone help me out here please.

Comment: What is the schema in the database for your data?

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#saving-refs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the docs of [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/), it says:

> If you specify only a single  condition in the `$elemMatch` expression, and are not using the `$not` or `$ne` operators inside of `$elemMatch`, `$elemMatch` can be omitted.

And in [Query an Array for an Element](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-for-an-element):

> To query if the array field contains at least one element with the specified value, use the filter { <field>: <value> } where <value> is the element value.

So in your case, you can simply do:

```
Account.find({investment: investment.id}).exec...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method retrieves entire documents.  Using elemMatch as a [query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/index.html#elemmatch-query) determines which document is selected from the collection.  It does not change the contents of the array of sub-documents.

To limit the contents of the `investment` array element, use elemMatch as a [projection operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html#elemmatch-projection).